# Adding to database and parsing on background

Tags: sql, database, performance

I am making a game of `Go` database program. There are `SGF` files which are short (hundreds of characters) game records which the program parses and adds to a `SQL` database.

When on `localhost` is it a good idea to first save files as strings and than parse them on background?

**Parsing** of *10,000 files* and adding to database takes approx *5 minutes* (will do some tunning here). I assume adding this many files and probably no more than 2,000,000 at once. 150,000 `SGF` files is approx 600MB.

Is it a good idea (performance, best-practise...) to **first put unparsed files as strings** and **parse on background**? Assuming `localhost`.

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: What exactly is this _parsing_ ? SGF is very easy to get into canonical form (just order the properties inside a node or move), so the only possible possibility for parsing would be to isolate "global" and "move" properties (and maybe split off variations) IMHO you don't need a database for this.

Comment: @wildplasser I am trying to get better performance when searching in tons of game records for specified beginning, specified pattern... So basically inserting nodes with move coordinates to a table.

Comment: If you only want to create an opening book: I don't think you should use an RDBMS. There is a nasty dual relation between sequences of moves and board positions that is unsolvable by current RDBMSs, IMHO. (plus, maybe later in the game: the _graph history interaction_ , which will spoil the design choises you ever made)